# Pandas replace nan with first non-nan value based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe of the following form: (many more columns than just these - removed for brevity)

```
import pandas as pd

headers = ['A','B','C']
data = [['p1','','v1'],
        ['p2','','ba'],
        ['p3',9,'fg'],
        ['p1',1,'fg'],
        ['p2',45,'af'],
        ['p3',1,'fg'],
        ['p1',1,'hf']
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=headers)

    A   B   C
0  p1      v1
1  p2      ba
2  p3   9  fg
3  p1   1  fg
4  p2  45  af
5  p3   1  fg
6  p1   1  hf
```

Column B has duplicates, whereby the *latest* value should be non-NA (but may not be)

I want to replace col B values with the latest non-NA value. Something like this:

```
unique_people = df['A'].unique()
for person in unique_people:
    sub_df = df[df['A'] == person]
    val = sub_df['B'].tail(1).values
    df['A'][df['A'] == person] = val  # this also doesnt work because its not inplace
```

Im sure theres a better way to do it, but im not sure how. Could anyone point a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace empty strings to missing values and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) for last non missing values per groups:

```
headers = ['A','B','C']
data = [['p1','','v1'],
        ['p2','','ba'],
        ['p3',9,'fg'],
        ['p1',1,'fg'],
        ['p2',45,'af'],
        ['p3',1,'fg'],
        ['p1','','hf']
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=headers)

df['B'] = df['B'].replace('', np.nan)

df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('last')
print (df)
    A     B   C
0  p1   1.0  v1
1  p2  45.0  ba
2  p3   1.0  fg
3  p1   1.0  fg
4  p2  45.0  af
5  p3   1.0  fg
6  p1   1.0  hf
```